# How can I run a specific page in my UWP app?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

So I am working on a UWP app that has multiple pages with full UI.

Currently I would run the entire app and then navigate to the page I want to test. I just want to know if there is an easier way to test a certain page and not have to go through the entire app?

I know you can go into App.xaml and change the code there to launch the page I want but is there a way to do it without hard coding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in VS2017:

1. in your solution properties set up a new configuration "Debug_MyPage" for testing MyPage:
   [image]
2. in your project properties, under 'Build' add a compilation symbol "MYPAGE" for the new configuration:
   [image]
3. in App.xaml.cs add a conditional line for navigating to MyPage:
   [image]

Now you can switch between "Debug" and "Debug_MyPage" configurations to launch to either the regular main page or the specific page you want to test without having to hardcode/change your source.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I would have liked it just to be like a button click but this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change application startup point to test specific Pages, so you should edit just startup `Page` `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)` event in App.xaml.cs to achieve your goals:

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
  {
   rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(yourPageToTestHere), e.Arguments);//edit this line
  }
```

Another solution is : You can navigate to test pages from `MainPage.xaml.cs` , just override it `OnNavigatedTo` event :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
   try
    {
     contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(yourTestPageHere));//navigate to yourTestPage page
    }
  catch (Exception)
   {
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks but this is the method I already knew and what I meant by trying to avoid hard coding it.